# SCSS. "#" deprecation in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sass, scss-lint, scss-mixins

I'm using something like this in my index.scss:

```
.some-class {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 50 50'><path d='M15.477 ... 50.836z' fill='#{$text-muted}'/><path d='M45.3 ... 10h6.1z' fill='#{$text-muted}'/></svg>");
}
```

But Chrome says to me:

`[Deprecation] Using unescaped '#' characters in a data URI body is deprecated and will be removed in M68, around July 2018. Please use '%23' instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5656049583390720 for more details.`

Comment: If you go to the [URL](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5656049583390720) the Chrome provides it tells you why it is deprecated.

Comment: I know the why. I'm asking for what to do in sass.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str-replace to replace # with %23.

```
.some-class {
   $urlString: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 50 50'><path d='M15.477 ... 50.836z' fill='#{$text-muted}'/><path d='M45.3 ... 10h6.1z' fill='#{$text-muted}'/></svg>");
   content: str-replace($urlString, "#", "%23");
}
```